# СПП цели или дополнительное?

Tags: синтаксис, спп, тип-придаточных

> Она билась за то, **чтобы соседи не мешали пластмассу с другим мусором,
>   *а сортировали и отвозили в специально отведенное место***.

Помогите, пожалуиста, понять:

1. Это целевое придаточное или дополнительное с целевым оттенком? (к сожалению у меня опять проблема с постановлением вопроса: *билась с какой целью?* или *билась за что?*)
2. В случае если это целевое придаточное, считается ли часть "*а сортировали и отвозили в специально отведенное место*" также целевым придаточным?
   Если нет, то какои это тип предложения? (если сократить предложение, получается союз "*чтобы*" можно трансферировать и на второе предложение? tipo "*Она билась за то, чтобы пластмассу сортировали и отвозили в специально отведенное место*." Или я ошибаюсь?)

Большое спасибо!

Comment: Билась за что? - За то, чтобы... ---Вопрос "с какой целью?" не согласуется с "за то, чтобы"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) **Это дополнительное придаточное с целевым оттенком**. (Другое название таких предложений  ―  предложения с приместоименными изъяснительными (дополнительными)   придаточными, или вмещающие СПП).

Их основная особенность заключается в том, что придаточное раскрывает содержание **указательного слова, наличие которого обязательно**: бились (за что?) ― за то, чтобы...  Обычно два союза используются в таких СПП: ЧТО и ЧТОБЫ.

2) Придаточное можно рассматривать как одно предложение с однородными сказуемыми:  соседи **не мешали, а сортировали и отвозили.**

**Примечание**. Можно сравнить с другими предложениями с союзом ЧТОБЫ:

Наша задача в том, чтобы скорее решить эту проблему (**дополнительное**  придаточное).

Я хочу, чтобы он приехал (придаточное **изъяснительное**).

Он уехал в город (зачем?), чтобы продолжить свое образование (придаточное **цели**).